# ethernet interface dropping connection intermittently Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, ethernet, realtek

I'm seeing an issue where my Realtek ethernet NIC will occasionally drop pings to the gateway. I have isolated the issue to my PC by using other PCs to test the link without issue. The connection is rock solid normally, but every 5-10 minutes, the machine will lose connectivity for about 15-30 seconds. During this time, the routing table remains unchanged and Ubuntu never reports the interface as down. Pings are failing the whole time. Any thoughts?

Ubuntu 16.04

Hardware:

- Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
  RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0a)

output of: `ethtool -i enp4s0f2`

```
driver: r8168
version: 8.041.00-NAPI
firmware-version: 
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:04:00.2
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no
```

Comment: Remove `r8168-dkms`

Comment: I installed r8168-dkms as a potential fix for this issue; I had the same issue before and after installing it. I just removed it and rebooted and the ethernet adapter does not work at all now. What do I need to do to reactivate the standard driver? Under lshw, I can see the device is UNCLAIMED.

Comment: When you installed the r8168 dkms you probably blacklisted the f8169. If so remove it from the blacklist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final solution to this was to install an Intel NIC into the machine. It has been rock solid for several months now. I don't know if the previous instability came from the Realtek NIC itself or the driver (I'm leaning toward the former), but things are working great now.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, so as to make finding this solution easier for others suffering the same, a likely cause is to be found in dnsmasq. See https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2317186 and http://biscuit.ninja/blog/dns-resolution-problems-in-ubuntu

Commenting out its loading in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` seems to have solved the issue for me.

Comment: I doubt its dnsmasq on Ubuntu 16.04. As I had similar problems with r8168 and r8169 fixed it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)